# roslyn not copied to bin for AspNet Mvc 5 project using PackageReference and Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers 2.0.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, roslyn

I recently migrated our project to PackageReference and upgraded Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers to version 2.0. As per their recommendation, I also removed Microsoft.Net.Compilers. After this move, the roslyn folder seems to not be copied to the bin directory during a publish operation in TeamCity. Locally it seems to work okay from VS and msbuild command line. Our TC build is calling msbuild as well, and Visual Studio is fully updated on our CI server.

Does anyone know a fix for this or have encountered this, or if it is a PackageReference issue or TeamCity issue or Visual Studio/MSBuild issue?

Notes:

- Removing Microsoft.Net.Compilers is irrelevant to the problem
- Cannot downgrade to 1.0.8 because we are using newer C# language features
- Research showed this was an issue that was resolved in 1.0.8, but I can't find anything related to 2.0.0
- `<Import>` elements in the csproj for the Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props and Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform2.0.0 were removed, but using PackageReference, my understanding is these are not used/needed

Comment: David, can you please open an issue at https://github.com/aspnet/RoslynCodeDomProvider/issues and share the build log if possible?

Comment: I will do this on Monday - we are indeed wondering if it is still a bug. The looked at the TC logs and I never see where it even tries to copy roslyn files - like it is entirely ignored